# Building Galaxy S3 Kernel for another Galaxy S3 variant

Tags: android, kernel, porting, galaxy, samsung-mobile

Basically what I am trying to do is build a kernel that has configs for one variant of the Galaxy S3 (d2usc) for another Galaxy S3 (d2cri) which they are both essentially the same model, but the kernels are not inter changeable. I have a defconfig that I have modified, but my question is, what device specific code needs to be added or changed in the kernel source to make it work?

Comment: May I suggest posting your question on the 'android-porting' google group [http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting]?  You're much more likely to find somebody who has actual experience of what you're trying to do there than here.

Comment: I was actually referred here because of the knowledge level of the users here when it comes to linux kernels (which android essentially runs a modified linux kernel)

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't think many of us are familiar with the specific hardware of the two models, which would be needed to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is go to the opensource page of samsung, which just got a bright new look. You can find it here http://opensource.samsung.com/ .

Hit Mobile, select "mobile phone" and choose your exact model. A list of available model variants can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III#Model_variants .

On the Samsung opensource page you can download the two different kernel sources. Unpack and compare them. Usually they come with a short readme on how to build and how to creat the config file. Compare them. And don't forget to compare the source. For linux there are some great comparison tools, like meld (http://meldmerge.org/).

On some devices the config flag is enabled which allows you to pull the config of the running kernel from your device. If you have the file permissions, you can usually just do a

```
adb pull /proc/config.gz myDeviceOriginalKernelConfig.gz
```

unpack and study it. On newer devices this config flag might not be set per default for "security" reasons.

good luck